# aggregate query results in Scala or in MySql

Tags: mysql, scala

I have a heavy query executed in MySql by a Scala code & Jooq; this is how it looks when converting to SQL from Jooq:

```
select t2.id,
       min(t2.date) as start_date,
       max(t2.date) as end_dtae,
       count(distinct t2.t) as total_t,
       count(distinct t2.x) as total_x,
       count(distinct t2.y) as y
from (select date, max(z) as latest
      from table
      where id = 1
        and z <= 50
      group by date) as t1
join table t2
     on t1.latest = t2.z
         and t1.date = t2.date
         and t2.id = 1;
```

this query is very slow because `table` is a huge table, and the whole process is even slower because we run over several `id`s and run this query for each one of them.
My question is whether aggregating the result (doing the `min`, `count` etc) by Scala itself after fetching the results as an array, instead of doing it in MySql, will give a better performance, and how can I do it?

Comment: Almost certainly it will be quicker in SQL, if for no other reason than it takes time to transfer large result sets over the network. You probably just don't have the right indexes to support this query. I'd expect a compound index on `(id, date, z)` may be right, but it needs to be tested.

Comment: Saying your table is "huge" is like complaining that you're so old when you're 40.

Comment: Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If so, why is more than 1 row involved?  I worry that you have over-simplified the _real_ problem.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  We at least need to see if you have desirable indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Self joins are always treacherous in SQL, because you're accessing the same table twice, and often, you don't have suitable indexes to simplify the access. Perhaps, the following equivalent query with single table access performs better? It depends on your data set of course. Just to give you an idea:

```sql
SELECT
  t.id,
  MIN(t.date) AS start_date,
  MAX(t.date) AS end_date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT t.t) AS t.total_t,
  COUNT(DISTINCT t.x) AS t.total_x,
  COUNT(DISTINCT t.y) AS t.total_y
FROM (
  SELECT
    id, date, t, x, y,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id, date ORDER BY z DESC) AS r
  FROM table
  WHERE id = 1 AND z <= 50
) t
WHERE r = 1
```

Obviously, an index on `table(id, z)` helps in any case.